# the output position is changing from the original text

Tags: c

I try to build codes that will delete the ';' and the words after it from some random text or document. It works, but somehow the position of the words (output) seem to be not in their original position anymore. Is it because the '\0' in my code? or something else? I couldn't figure it out. The text example is look like this:

abcdefghijkl    ; qrwetyruiop

asdasasdasd            ; qwertyuiop

fgfghfghfgh           ; asdfghjkl

fhfghftytyt          ; 123456789

bnmbnmbnmb            ; qazwsxedc

my code to remove it look like this:

*some code of read line by line* 
int i;
for(int i=1; instructions[i] != '\0'; i++)

```
    {
        if(instructions[i] == ';')

            {

                instructions[i] = '\0'; 

                break;
            }
    }
printf("%d: %s", i, instructions);
i++;
```

when i compiled and run it, the output were changing in position, for example:

gcc -std=c99 -Wall something.c -o something.exe

./something.exe

abcdefghijkl    asdasasdasd            fgfghfghfgh
     fhfghftytyt         bnmbnmbnmb

the expected output is that the words before the ';' sign left unchanged in their position just like this:

abcdefghijkl

asdasasdasd

fgfghfghfgh

fhfghftytyt

bnmbnmbnmb

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking, what is your expected output?

Comment: Edit your question! Don't add extra information in the comments.

Comment: Also what is the difference between what you output and what you just said in the comment?

Comment: ok sorry i already edit my question.

Comment: All strings in C are understood to be null terminated.  Changing a character in the string to `'\0'` definitely has the effect of truncating the string.  Printout on a `%s` will include nothing right of a null character, including any newline (`'\n'`) characters.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a newline to the end of your template string, hence `"%d: %s\n"`, because you got rid of the newlines in the original by cutting off everything to the right of where the `';'`s were.

Also, there's [an `index()` function](http://phpunixman.sourceforge.net/index.php/man/index/3) that makes it unnecessary to loop through the lines.